# How to fetch data using JOIN clause in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to match contact from both tables and fetch details of `mother` in mysql using JOIN clause in php.

Table `students`

| name | mother | mcontact |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Larry | Wanda | 12345678 |

Table `parents`

| name | parent_of | relation | contact | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wanda | Larry | mother | 12345678 | any other details |

And this is my code

```
$user_query = 'SELECT students.mcontact FROM `students` JOIN `parents` ON students.mcontact=parents.contact';
$user_result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $user_query);

while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($user_result)){

  echo $users->name}
```

It is showing me an error `Undefined property $name`

If there is any other way to do it please enlighten me.

Comment: you need to include `students.name` in the select, your only returning `students.mcontact`

Answer (score 0):

Also, as Lawrence mentioned abouve, adding the students.name to the sql query like so.

```
$user_query = 'SELECT students.mcontact, students.name FROM `students` JOIN `parents` ON students.mcontact=parents.contact';
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_object()` just fetches one row, not an array of rows. You can't use `foreach` there.

Comment: You're confusing it with `mysqli_fetch_all($user_result, MYSQLI_OBJECT)`

Comment: Ah. That's right. Will edit to not confuse. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_query = 'SELECT students.mcontact,students.name,parents.name as parentName FROM `students` JOIN `parents` ON students.mcontact=parents.contact';
$user_result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $user_query);
```